# How to show a view inside another view on only first row?

Tags: entities, views

I need to display a view inside another view and I'm using [Views field views](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module, It works well, but I need the field (view) only appears in the first row result of the view page, like the following.

- View page - results

  - Title node 1
  - Image node 1
  - View field 1 (this should appear only here)
  - Title node 2
  - Image-node 2

Comment: is there any relationship between node and view field?

Comment: not really. But there is a vocabulary in nodes where each node receives a different term.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if [Views nodes split](http://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) module will be useful for your situation as @DnBase mentioned.

However, because you're using [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view); you can follow the following steps to achieve what you're looking for:

- Edit field view actual view (referenced view)
- Add `Global: Null` from **CONTEXTUAL FILTERS** menu

[image: Add contextual filters]

- From the next dialog box that appear, select `Hide view` from *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE* fieldset.
- Then from *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED* fieldset, check `Specify validation criteria` and select `PHP Code` from validator dropdown menu
- Then add the following code in `PHP Validate code` field
- From `Action to take if filter value does not validate` dropdown menu select `Hide view`

**Code:**

```
if($argument == 1) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

[image: Global null dialog box]

- Now edit the main view
- Add `Global: View result counter` from **FIELDS** menu, then from field configuration dialog box, check `Exclude from display`
- Then edit `Global: View` field, from field configuration dialog box, add this replacement pattern `[%counter]` into `Contextual filters` field

[image: Global view field view]

By applying these steps, you'll notice that view field will only appear on first item.

Comment: Hey, That's great! But in my case something went wrong because the result is appearing on the second line. I do not know if I did something wrong. My criterion sorting is by taxonomy term: Weight

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Try to display **View result counter** field and see if the first item output number **1** also make sure the **View result count** field is on top of the fields

Comment: Yes, the number 1 is first item output of View result counter field. I tried to change to 0 but it doesn't work!

Comment: its showing this error message:
Notice: Undefined property: views_handler_field_counter::$last_render in views_field_view_handler_field_view->get_token_value() (line

Comment: have you rearranged **View result counter** field to be first field under **Fields** menu

Comment: WOW!!! Perfect!! Solved, tanks very much Aboodred1!!

Comment: You are welcome @AngieBlonde :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways to 'split' the displays in your view so far:

1. Use an 'Attachement' display and attach it to your view.
2. Use [Views nodes split](https://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) module. See lullabot's [review](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/module-monday-views-nodes-split) to have an idea.

BTW you can still use a display mode to display your content type fields in your view if you want. See my post [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71592/use-a-view-to-show-multiple-content-types-but-only-show-a-field-if-it-belongs-t/71621#71621).

edit: The second solution will work only if your display mode contains the view by using EVA  or Viewfield module. So never mind but I leave it just for the Views nodes split module if you're interested. In your case the first solution will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use views template file, and put some PHP scripts using flags to ensure that the view field renders only first time.